# C# ASP.NET PostBackUrl to an anchor

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this link button here

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton" CssClass="Button" runat="server">Link Text</asp:LinkButton>
```

and I am assign it a PostBackURL in my code behind like so

```
lnkButton.PostBackUrl = "#video";
```

but its not going to an anchor div video, instead I am getting a Page Not Found Error

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to navigate to another div on the same page then I think you can use simply `href` property with `Id` of your div.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="dd" runat="server" href="#video" Text="Go to Video" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

PostBackUrl should be used when you want the page to navigate elsewhere on a postback.  You want intra-page navigation, so you should use NavigateUrl property.

Comment: NavigateURL does not come up when I do lnkButton. do I have to use something?

Comment: I think **@AgentD5** is referring to `HyperLink.NavigateUrl` so use a HyperLink control rather than a LinkButton control.

Answer (score 0):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),“anchor”, “location.hash = ‘#mainGrid’;”, true);
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.